# Wrong text encoding in string sent to javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a javascript method which is receiving a UTF-8 encoded string (ViewBag.errorText), and uses this as a parameter to a new function.

The problem is that the text displayed in `show_error_dialog` is displaying the html escaped characters (`&#230;&#248` etc') and not the intended ("æåø" etc.).

I presume the problem is the enclosed `<text>` tags but can't seem to get around this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    function performLoadOperations() {
        @if(ViewBag.errorText!= null) {
            <text>show_error_dialog('@ViewBag.errorText');</text>
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think all Razor-inserted text is HTML-encoded by default. Use `Html.Raw()` to pass the string unencoded.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    function performLoadOperations() {
        @if(ViewBag.errorText!= null) {
            <text>show_error_dialog('@Html.Raw(ViewBag.errorText)');</text>
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This opens you up to an XSS exploit, you need to re-encode errorText for insertion into javascript.

Comment: Couldn't understand can you please explan Mr.Fox

Answer (score 5):

Use:
@Html.Raw(Ajax.JavaScriptStringEncode(Model))

to safely insert values into javascript

Comment: Can you explain a bit about this, why this is safely and what does exactly each function? Thanks a lot, this worked for me !!!

Answer (score 1):

just use [javascript escape](http://ecmanaut.blogspot.com/2006/07/encoding-decoding-utf8-in-javascript.html) function:

```
function encode_utf8( s )
{
  return unescape( encodeURIComponent( s ) );
}

function decode_utf8( s )
{
  return decodeURIComponent( escape( s ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but i think there was unescape() function with js. Try to pass your text with it. It might help