# What's with Razor between my script tags?

Tags: javascript, encoding, razor

I've got a Razor string in my view which I have put inside JavaScript script tags. The encoding gets wrong, but when I move it from the script tags the encoding gets right.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var deletemessage = "@Resources.Resource.MessageDelete";
</script>
```

I get this:

```
Vill du verkligen ta bort den h&#228;r?
```

And I want this:

```
Vill du verkligen ta bort den här?
```

What's going on?

Comment: Define "wrong" and "right". What is your intended result, and what do you get?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6291198/wrong-text-encoding-in-string-sent-to-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Html.Raw()`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var deletemessage = "@Html.Raw(Resources.Resource.MessageDelete)";
</script>
```